# Program doesn't produce any output

Tags: c

I tried writing a code that gets up to 10 words, and if everything is a pangram it prints that it's a pangram. The thing is about this code is that even if the user enters 7 words that are a pangram, the for loop needs to stop and print that the sentence formed out of this words is indeed a pangram.
I wrote the code and it compiles just fine, the problem is the exe file, I try to execute it and it doesn't work. Can you guys help me?
my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define MAX_WORDS 10
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 10
#define TEN 10

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH] = { 0 }; 

    for(i = 0; i < TEN; i++)
    {

        flag = 0;
        fgets(words[i], MAX_WORDS, stdin);
        //inputs the name
        if(words[i][strlen(words[i])-1] == '\n')
        {
            words[i][strlen(words[i])-1] = 0;
        }
        //makes sure there is no problem
        for(p = 0; p <= i; p++)
        {   
            for(k = 97; k < 123; k++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < strlen(words[i]); j++)
                {
                    if(k == words[i][j])
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                    }

                }

            }       

        }
        if(flag)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter == 26)
        {
            i = 10;
            printf("It's a pangram?\nYes!");
        }
    }





    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a detailed enough diagnostic. Can you better describe what it is you're trying to achieve, what output you're getting, if any, with particular attention paid to *any* errors generated by this code? What is this code supposed to do? It's very important to be as specific as you can, and this may require doing some additional investigation as to the root cause of your problem before posting a question.

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean that it doesn't execute. It looks like it's loading but nothing happens

Comment: "Doesn't execute" as in "doesn't produce any useful output"? If that's the case, time to step through your code in a debugger and find out why.

Comment: it doesn't produce any output for some reason

Comment: Another thing to note is your outer `for` loop should be `i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS` not this unrelated constant named `TEN`. What does that have to do with anything? Don't call constants by what they are, but what they represent. Nothing more absurd than seeing in code `#define TEN 11`.

Comment: Similarly, `fgets(words[i], MAX_WORDS, stdin);` should be `fgets(words[i], MAX_WORD_LENGTH, stdin);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what missing in your code. You forgot to add the `break` statement after setting the flag. And incrementing the counter should be part of words iterating for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define MAX_WORDS 10
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 10
#define TEN 10

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH] = { 0 }; 

    for(i = 0; i < TEN; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        fgets(words[i], MAX_WORDS, stdin);
        //inputs the name
        if(words[i][strlen(words[i])-1] == '\n')
        {
            words[i][strlen(words[i])-1] = 0;
        }
        //makes sure there is no problem
        for(p = 0; p <= i; p++)
        {   
            for(k = 97; k < 123; k++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < strlen(words[i]); j++)
                {
                    if(k == words[p][j])
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(flag)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }       

        }
        if(counter == 26)
        {
            i = 10;
            printf("It's a pangram?\nYes!");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you should try to debug the code yourself first.

For starters, I would stick a printf at the beginning of the `for(i = 0; i < TEN; i++)` loop to ensure the code is actually being executed. Of course you can put it in every single other loop to get some idea where the code is going.

One mistake I'm noticing is in here: `fgets(words[i], MAX_WORDS, stdin);`. The second parameter to fgets is expected to be the max word length and not the maximum number of words.